# The socket Accept method does not throw a SocketException

Tags: c#, sockets

I wrote a socket app and use the `Close()` method to wait a state of socket:

```
serverSocket =
    new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6, SocketType.Stream,
           ProtocolType.Tcp);
serverSocket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IPv6, (SocketOptionName) 27, 0);
serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.IPv6Any, this.listenPort));
serverSocket.Listen(4);

serverSocket.Accept()
```

When I call the `serverSocket.Close()` in another thread, the `Accept()` method does not throw the socketexception which I used as a socket state. Any ideas how I fix this?

Comment: `Close` happen before the `Accept` call?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use BeginAccept or AcceptAsync which will allow you to wait for connections without blocking, and in its own way solves your issue.  It's very easy to develop asynchronous socket code in .NET by chaining callbacks to asynchronous functions.  This has the added benefit of not consuming any threads during periods of inactivity.

Comment: In my case, I need the thread name to identify the something, but the thread which beginaccept use is a threadpool thread, as you may know, the thread name can only be set once, that's my problem, thanks

Comment: You can use the state field to track that additional information rather than using the thread name.  This is a significantly better design.  Create a ConnectionState class, add the fields you need, and then pass it into each Begin*() socket operation, then recover it from each callback in IAsyncResult.UserState

Comment: Thanks Jeremiah, finally i found reason in my case, the details is  two processes are dead locked, which make the call of the Close method of the socket class failed, for example, process A start B, while B wants to close A, but wait A's out put stream,  in MSDN, i got the answer here; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx ,